# Node.js how to select from MongoDB inside a for or foreach?

Tags: node.js

I have this code:

```
result.rides.forEach(function(ride) {
      var query = {
        "by.phone": req.body.myPhone,
        "inRide": ride["_id"].toString(),
      };
      db.offers.findOne(query, function(err, docs) {
        if (docs) {
          ride.offered = true;
        }
      });
    });
```

Now, I want to return the result.rides at the end of the `forEach`,
how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert each iteration into it's own `awaitable` and wait for them all to finish e.g.

```
async func() {
  const queries = result.rides.map(r =>
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const query = {
          'by.phone': req.body.myPhone,
          'inRide': r._id.toString()
        };
        const docs = await db.offers(query);
        if (docs) {
          r.offered = true;
        }
        return resolve();
      } catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
      }
    })
  );
  await Promise.all(queries);
  // do something with rides
}
```

Comment: @Raz guess I made the assumption you were a. using Node v6+ and b. this code would need to be inside its own async function. Can update to demonstrate.

Comment: I have now updated to v9 but this still not working.. I receive errors..

Comment: It returns cb is not a function..]

Comment: @Raz there is no reference to `cb` in my example so not related to the code I've given.